# What is the best way to check if a Javascript Array contains any of the elements of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As per question title, I'm using:

```
Array.prototype.containsAny = function (otherArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < otherArray.length; i++) 
     if (this.includes(otherArray[i])) 
       return true;

  return false;
};


let a1 =  [3, 5, 9];
let a2 = [4, 5];
a1.containsAny(a2);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `Array#includes` is a _O(n)_ operation compared to `Set#has` which is _O(1)_ - If you're doing this as a repeated operation, the whitelist should be made into a Set first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let a1 =  [3, 5, 9];
let a2 = [4, 5];

function containsAny(a1,a2){
  return a1.some(e=> a2.includes(e))
}

console.log(containsAny(a1,a2))
console.log(containsAny(a1, [1,2]))
```